# What's wrong with my PHP code? Can't see errors because it's creating a server error

Tags: php

Working on some PHP, and keep encountering the Server error 500.

Here's my code, what am I doing wrong? I've tried a lot, but I have a feeling it's to do with line 17. I'm a novice coder, so I'm probably doing something simply wrong but any help is appreciated.

```
$category_id = '';
if( isset( $_GET['id'])) {
    $category_id = $_GET['id'];
}

for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($category_id); $i++);

include('dbconnect.php');
$title = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '$i'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($title);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$title = $result(1('name'));
include('base-template.php');
```

Comment: Try to debug your code using `exit;`

Comment: $title = $result(1('name')); what is it?

Comment: Add debug information like which lines get executed, post included files (`base-template.php`, `dbconnect.php`) and add error information for db access.

Comment: what else to say but *check your logs*.

Comment: $title = $result['name']; use like that...

Comment: maybe  $result(1('name')); from what I can get out of this is your trying to select something like this? $result[1]['name'] also what is the point of the for loop

Comment: and this is failing you `$result(1('name'));` wrong type of brackets.

Comment: yes @Fred-ii-: line no 17 is the last line, before l('name')

Comment: can't see errors? display them then `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also if by any chance you have are trying to select multiple categories the loop will fail since your trying to include $i as the id which will iterate over N category_id, but never including the category_id. Selecting should be done inside the loop, and the select will fire only once since its after the loop thus the max $i will be in your select

Answer (score 3):

Errors

1. **Missing** `{}` in for loop
2. `for` loop **never ends** with `;` at end
3. Each and every time you are **including** `dbconnect`.
4. `$category_id` should define as **array**
5. `$result(1('name'))` is unclear. No idea what you expect too

[Check Fred-ii comment on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811827/whats-wrong-with-my-php-code-cant-see-errors-because-its-creating-a-server-e/34811962#comment57365632_34811827)

Comment: add this also... bro $title = $result(1('name'));

Comment: @devpro added as well

Comment: Actually there is no for loop just a for line the `;` make the loop run x time and do nothing

Comment: 1. no error here. 2. no error here. 3. no error; 1-2 think of it as do while loop, 3. you can include any number times dbconnect and base-template, which will only result in IO overhead, not an error

Comment: yeah, that `$result(1(` no idea what they want to do here. It's as if `1` is a function. *df?*

Comment: @devpro Actually, [this is the *real* genius...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZZDqwKASbI) ;-)

Comment: *a definite classic* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Mann.. You taking me away from stack too loony tones in youtube. ;)

Comment: Call it *"Time well spent"* ;-)